# SQL 'UNION ALL' like implementation in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There are two collections:

Sales

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ba0bfb8d1acdc0de716e839"),
  "invoiceNumber" : 1,
  "saleDate" : ISODate("2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  "totalTaxAmount" : 613,
  "subTotalAmount" : 2000,
  "totalAmount" : 2613,
  "balance" : 2613,
  "financialYear" : "2018-2019",
  "modeOfPayment" : "Digital Transfer",
  "customerName": "Acme Inc"
}
```

Transactions

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5bbb4e131fb8af0dc645212d"),
  "transactionNumber" : 1    
  "transactionDate" : ISODate("2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
  "transactionType" : "Income",
  "partyName" : "Acme Inc",
  "transactionMode" : "Digital Transfer",
  "amount" : 2613,
  "paidItems" : [ 
      {
          "orderId" : "5b90a7d62bb5a21be4ff97e3",
          "invoiceNumber" : "1",
          "orderType" : "sale",
          "totalAmount" : 2613,
          "balance" : 613,
          "payingAmount" : 2000
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to retrieve sales and transactions as 'heading' for the specific party (i.e. customerName, partyName) between two dates (i.e. saleDate, transactionDate) ordered by date; as follows:

```
[
  {
    "date": ISODate("2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "heading": "Sale",
    "particulars": "Invoice # 1",
    "amount": 2613
  },
  {
    "date": ISODate("2018-09-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "heading": "Payment by Digital Transfer",
    "particulars": "Transaction # 1",
    "amount": 2000
  }
]
```

I researched and tried with [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/index.html), [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) but it's not returning what's desired.

Switching from SQL to MongoDB. In SQL following query works fine:

```
select sale_date as dated, 'Sale' as heading, 'Invoice # ' + 
convert(varchar(12),invoice_number) as particulars, 
convert(varchar(12), total) as amount, 
from sales where sale_date between @from_date AND @to_date AND 
customer_name=@customer_name
UNION ALL
select transaction_date as dated, 'Payment by ' + transaction_mode as 
heading, 'Transaction # ' + convert(varchar(12), transaction_id) as 
particulars, convert(varchar(12), amount) as amount from transactions 
where transaction_date between @from_date AND @to_date AND 
party_name=@customer_name
order by dated DESC
```

There's a [feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23201) filed in the MongoDB community and it's 'unresolved'.

I would like to know is there any way for this within mongoShell or MongoDB driver (mongoose / JS). Using current stable versions of MongoDB, nodejs, express, and mongoose. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post what you have tried yet

Comment: Sure. This is not a full proof as I was just giving it a try.        
db.sales.aggregate([
  { $match: { "saleDate":{$gte: ISODate("2018-09-01"),$lte: ISODate("2018-09-10")}, "customerName":'Acme Inc' }},
  { $lookup: {
         from: "transactions",
         localField: "customerName",
         foreignField: "partyName", 
         as: "fromTransactions"
      }
   },
   {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$fromTransactions", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
   },
   { $project: { saleDate: 1, invoiceNumber: 1, amount:1, fromTransactions: 1 } }
])

Comment: This is retrieving sale entries each documented with an array of transactions with matching customerName. I know this is not at all correct but i was trying it with aggregate but seems that it's not what I want as I need to get sales AND transactions ordered by date. Or may be I'm making a mistake.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724403/fetch-data-from-2-collections-in-mongodb-in-single-query/52724921#52724921

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Keeping in mind, 16 MB BSON limit of $lookup the solution you proposed is good for interim use. Same as of the question you referred, what about sorting by date (it's not been mentioned in the answer); are we supposed to sort resulting concatenated 'data' collection? I specified it in the query but no help. Any suggestions.

Comment: okay. now I can sort it perfectly...projected 'saleDate' and 'transactionDate' as 'dated' and then specified { "$sort": { "dated": 1 } } within aggregate pipeline...@AnthonyWinzlet can you please post an answer including the query from a referred question as it was absolutely useful...So that I can accept it as an answer :)

Comment: Could you post your query which worked for you? I need to have a look

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet It's almost same as of you suggested, except '$sort'. As the query was not fitting within comments section here, I've created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/man_in/zpfay6on/1/

Comment: Great!!! You got it. Posted an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.sales.aggregate([
  { "$limit": 1 },
  { "$facet": {
    "collection1": [
      { "$limit": 1 },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "sales",
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "date": { "$gte": ISODate("2018-09-01"), "$lte": ISODate("2018-09-10") },
            "customer.name": customerName
          }},
          { "$project": {
            "_id":0, "dated": "$saleDate", "heading": "Sale", "particulars": "$invoiceNumber",
            "amount": "$totalAmount", "modeOfPayment": null
          }}
        ],
        "as": "collection1"
      }}
    ],
    "collection2": [
      { "$limit": 1 },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "transactions",
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "transactionDate": { "$gte": ISODate("2018-09-01"), "$lte": ISODate("2018-09-10") },
            "userId": userId, "partyName": customerName
          }},
          { "$project": {
            "_id":0, "dated": "$transactionDate", "heading": "Payment","particulars": "$transactionNumber",
            "amount": "$amount", "paymentMode": "$transactionMode"
          }}
        ],
        "as": "collection2"
      }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$concatArrays": [
        { "$arrayElemAt": ["$collection1.collection1", 0] },
        { "$arrayElemAt": ["$collection2.collection2", 0] },
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } },
  { "$sort": { "dated": -1 }}
])
```

Comment: Wondering if 'allowDiskUse: true' would be of any help to counter BSON limit?

Comment: Until you have `$match` condition you don't need to worry. [`allowDiskUse: true`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#aggregate-data-using-external-sort) will only help to handle large data set.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think so that you can perform a union on 2 different collections in mongodb.

However you can get data from both collections using q.all and afterwards make a union from them using your own function or may be third party module like lodash.

The only way you can perform union in mongodb is as mentioned here.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/

Comment: Your link is about the logical union of 2 arrays, not a relational db union.

Comment: That is not my answer. I am just showing him that mongodb does not support it.

Comment: @SagarChaudhary I see. I had a thought about it, but I was wondering if there is any way. If not possible in MongoDB shell then retrieving two different collections and formatting them as per requirement is the only option I'm left with.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: The technique presented below is not exactly advisable. ;) This is true in particular when dealing with big collections. However, it can be used to achieve the identical effect as a SQL `UNION ALL` from MongoDB v3.6 onwards.

Given a collection `first` and a collection `second`:

```
db.first.aggregate([{
    $group: { // create an array to hold all documents of the first collection
        "_id": null,
        "first": {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: { // perform some kind of ridiculous lookup which will return all documents from the second collection in an array
        from: "second",
        let: { /* we do not need any variables */ },
        pipeline: [ { $match: { /* this filter will match every document */ } } ],
        as: "second"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "all": { $concatArrays: [ "$first", "$second" ] } // merge the two collections
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$all" // flatten the resulting array
}, {
    $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$all" } // move content of "all" field all the way up 
}], {
    allowDiskUse: true // make sure we do not run into memory issues
})
```

Comment: How to use match ignore case sensitivity with like clause