# Fetch data from 2 collections in mongodb in single query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I wanted to fetch data from 2 independent collections and sort the results based on `date` through a single query. Is that even possible in `mongodb`? I have collections:

**OrderType1**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Hello1",
    "date": "2016-09-23T15:07:38.000Z"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Hello1",
    "date": "2015-09-23T15:07:38.000Z"
}
```

**OrderType2**

```
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Hello3",
        "date": "2012-09-23T15:07:38.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Hello4",
        "date": "2018-09-23T15:07:38.000Z"
    }
```

**Expected Result**

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Hello3",
        "date": "2012-09-23T15:07:38.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Hello1",
        "date": "2015-09-23T15:07:38.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Hello1",
        "date": "2016-09-23T15:07:38.000Z"
    },

    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Hello4",
        "date": "2018-09-23T15:07:38.000Z"
    }
]
```

Now, I want to fetch both types of `orders` in a single query sorted by date.

Comment: what should be the expected output?

Comment: It should be an array of combined data from both collections sorted by date. I have edited the question and added expected response/ I can do this in using 2 queries, get the data and sort it. But I am not sure  if if can be done in 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above but I think you should use two queries because for the large data set [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) pipeline will breach [**BSON limit**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) of **16mb**. But also It depends upon your `$match` condition or `$limit`. If they are applied to the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) pipeline then your aggregation would work perfectly.

```
db.OrderType1.aggregate([
  { "$limit": 1 },
  { "$facet": {
    "collection1": [
      { "$limit": 1 },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "OrderType1",
        "pipeline": [{ "$match": { } }],
        "as": "collection1"
      }}
    ],
    "collection2": [
      { "$limit": 1 },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "OrderType2",
        "pipeline": [{ "$match": { } }],
        "as": "collection2"
      }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$concatArrays": [
        { "$arrayElemAt": ["$collection1.collection1", 0] },
        { "$arrayElemAt": ["$collection2.collection2", 0] },
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks. For moderate sized collections, which approach would be more optimal in terms of query time, this single query or 2 queries and then sorting?

Comment: I think you should use two queries because for the large data set `$lookup` will breach BSON limit of **16mb**. But also It depends upon your `$match` condition or `$limit`.