# MongoDB View that merges data from two collections with identical schema

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I've seen variants of this question but not quite exactly the same as my scenario (at least not in recent years).

I have two collections, `completedorders` and `completedsales`. They have identical schema with basically this important data:

```
{ 
"type" : "IRON_BLOCK", 
"price" : 10.0
}
```

I'm trying to create a view that is the aggregate of **both collections in order to determine an average price** based on each type. I want to average the price of IRON_BLOCK types from **both** collections into a single `averageprices` collection, but am unsure the exact lookup and/or unwind stages to go through.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Do the records in the collections have any relation? Anyway see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715308/sql-union-all-like-implementation-in-mongodb

Comment: Only identical schema. The difference is merely what kind of order is fulfilled (sale or buy order); though I may've overly complicated the whole process by having two collections when a single-collection with merely a boolean to note the difference may've been wholly sufficient.